# likelihood view of F-test

Tags: likelihood-ratio, f-test, non-central

Suppose I observe independent $X, Y$ where $X/\sigma^2 \sim \chi^2(\nu_1,\delta)$ and $Y/\sigma^2 \sim \chi^2(\nu_2,0)$, where $\sigma^2$ is some nuisance parameter. (The notation $\chi^2(\nu,\delta)$ refers to a non-central $\chi^2$ with $\nu$ degrees of freedom and non-centrality parameter $\delta$.) The usual F-test proceeds by computing
$$
F = \frac{X / \nu_1}{Y / \nu_2},
$$
and comparing $F$ to a (non-central) F distribution.

Suppose for $0 \le \delta_1 < \delta_2$ I wanted to test the hypothesis $H_a : \delta = \delta_1$ versus $H_b : \delta = \delta_2$ using the likelihood ratio test. I believe I would compute
$$
\lambda = \frac{g(F;\nu_1,\nu_2,\delta_1)}{g(F;\nu_1,\nu_2,\delta_2)},
$$
where $g$ is the likelihood of the non-central F distribution, and reject $H_a$ if $\lambda$ is sufficiently small.

The question: is the ratio $\lambda$ here monotonic in the statistic $F$? That is, does the LRT here reduce to "reject $H_a$ if $F$ is sufficiently large"? (The analogous result about the $t$-test was shown to be the case by [Kruskal](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177728857))

Comment: What $Y$ has to do with testing about a parameter of another, independent random variable?

Comment: $X$ has an unknown $\sigma^2$ scaling, which we get rid of by dividing by $Y$. This is a standard ANOVA type problem.